# How to write to Python dictionary without loading the dictionary into memory?

Tags: python, dictionary, bigdata, pickle, large-data

I have a large table that I want to convert to a Python dictionary but I don't want to load all of the data into memory.

**Is it possible to actively write to a pickle dump without building the object first?**

For example:

```py
import gzip
f_out = open("output.dict.pkl.gz", "wb")

with open("table.tsv", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            fields = line.split("\t")
            k = fields[3]
            v = fields[1]

            # Pseudocode
            f_out[k] = v # I know this won't work but just so you can see my goal

# Close the pickle file
f_out.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your keys are strings, you can use the `shelve` module to make a `dict`-like object that's backed by a minimalist database, where the keys are strings, and the values are individually pickled values. You should also use the `csv` module to parse TSV data properly:

```
import csv
import shelve

with open("table.tsv", newline="") as f_in, shelve.open("output.db") as shelf:
    for row in csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='\t'):
        if row:
            k = row[3]
            v = row[1]
            shelf[k] = v
```

Importantly, this means when you load it later to read a handful of keys, you don't need to load the whole thing into memory then either.

Comment: Shelve is a good option, but values are loaded into memory as they're accessed, so if a value is very large, retrieving it could consume a lot of memory.

Comment: @PedroLobito: Yep. But as long as you don't use `writeback=True` when opening the shelf, it won't be cached on the shelf itself; the memory you use will be tied to how many of the things you access that you *keep* (save off to variables or other in-memory data structures). If you do use `writeback=True`, then manual calls to `.sync()` would be needed to clear the cache if it starts growing too large.

Comment: Interesting, so this functions similar to a pickle object but is called a shelf?

Comment: @O.rka: It acts like a `dict`, but every time you assign to a key, it pickles the value, and stores the key and value to an underlying database on disk. So it's a pickle per-value, rather than one large pickle, which is how you achieve the lower memory (but likely higher disk) consumption.